# Get data from mongo while post request in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple POST request with sending mail by nodemailer.

```
app.post("/sendMail", function(req, res) {
    nodemailer.sendMail({ from: 'xx', to: userEmail }, function(error, info) {
        if (error) {
            return res.send(500, 'Internal error, try again later');
        }

        res.send(200, 'Mail sent!');
    });
});
```

However, for security reasons, Im not storing user mail anywhere in client-side. But in the request, I have user `id`.

Single collection in db looks like:

```
{
   id: '1312feew3',
   email: 'patrick@hotmail.com',
}
```

So if my `req.body.id` equals to `1312feew3`, I need to get that specified collection and take the `email` out from it

#### What I tried

I tried to do simple:

```
var userEmail = getUserById(req.body.id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send(400, 'Something went wrong');
    }
    return res.json(user);
}).email;
```

(I placed it on the second line in the first code)

Unfortunately it didnt work as I expected.

**It doesnt throw any errors, however the mail is not being sent.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `getUserById` is async, it can't return the user directly and you have to access it from within the callback function:

```
getUserById(req.body.id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send(400, 'Something went wrong');
    }

    var userEmail = user.email;

    // Send the email here, within the callback as well.
    ...

    return res.json(user);
});
```

Comment: Thats kinda weird that getting something from db (which is on server side, aswell as the function itself) is async. Anyways it did the trick. Thank u :)